# Define getter / setter in object function

Tags: javascript, oop, setter, getter

I'm learning JavaScript, and was wondering if it was possible to define getters and setters in object functions.
The main difference is the way of calling it, if defined as `getFullName = function()`, I should call the method as `myObj.getFullName()`, however, as for arrays, a getter allows for it to be called as a simple property `myObj.fullName` (without parenthesis).

As I saw in MDN reference (http://mzl.la/1CIUuIw), it is easily done in Object Literals:

```
var obj = {
    get var(){
        return "something";
    }
}
```

However, I can't do it on object functions like so:

```
function obj(name, lname){
    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = lname;

    get fullName(){
         return this.name + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}
```

Getting a "Unexpected identifier" error...

Comment: post the reference where you saw this cuz this looks wrong to me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As `get XX(){}` is used for `var obj = {};` But here you use a constructor to create new object. So you should use [MDN - Object.defineProperty()](http://Object.defineProperty()).

And if you want the `fullName` apply on all object create from `obj`, apply it on its prototype.

```js
function obj(name, lname){
  this.name = name;
  this.lastName = lname;
}

Object.defineProperty(obj.prototype, 'fullName', {
  get : function() {
    return this.name + " " + this.lastName;
  }
});

var aObj = new obj("first", 'lastN');
console.log(aObj.fullName);
```

UPDATE:
If you want a more straight way, and not scared to try new things, then `ES2015`'s class notation can do it more easily:

```
// ES2015 - class
class obj {
  constructor(name, lname) {
    this.name = name;
    this.lname = lname;
  }

  // Define getter method for fullName
  get fullName() {
    return this.name + " " + this.lastName;
  }
}

var aObj = new obj('Billy', 'Hallow');
console.log(aObj.fullName);
```

Currently most browsers don't support that, if you want to use this in your site, you need to use js compilers like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile it from ES2015 to ES5.

Babel also provide a [playground](https://babeljs.io/repl/) for those who has interest in ES2015, you can copy above codes to the playground to see how it works.

Comment: Hi again @fuyushimoya, I was wondering if you know how to make getters and setters interact with private variables. For instance, i have a constructor: `function person(){ var a = 0; }` to which I added a getter `get: function() { return a;}`. But it throws `a is not defined`... and obviously `this.a` is undefined as well... Any ideas?

Comment: If there are no other (function/var) ref to a, the a will be collected after the function executed, would you create some snippet on jsfiddle to show what you want to achieve?

Comment: I've create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7maxth35/6/), maybe it's what you expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem was that `Object.defineProperty` was outside the constructor, using `constructorName.prototype`.

Comment: Then it can't, you the `a` in the constructor is only visible to the constructor function and functions defined inside it, so you have to use what I post on that jsfiddle to access that.

Comment: does this have the side effect that the property is now available outside the `obj function`?

Comment: Which property do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Just make a variable and assign the function to it.

```
function obj(name, lname){
    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = lname;

    this.fullName = function(){
        return this.name + " " + this.lastName;
    };
}
```

Try to read something about [Javascript closure](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) if you want to know more about it.

Furthermore, this link, [Javascript methods](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_methods.asp), is explaining EXACTLY what you need, which is adding a method to an object. And a getter is traditionally just a method.

Comment: The difference between a `getter` and a `method` is that when calling it, you don't need the parenthesis, it is like `length` for an array for instance. I was just wondering if it was possible

Comment: There is no such identifier as get in Javascript as far as I know, so I guess that is where your error is coming from. In Javascript you can either use closure or nested functions. I showed you closure, which is a Javascript method http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_methods.asp. Your example is right there!

Comment: I understand the comment, however check the reference link in the question. JavaScript accepts getters and setters as functions, enabling them to be called as properties and not mehtods.
You can also check the accepted answer from @fuyushimoya

Comment: @JoColina Yes but then again, it's exactly the same. The disadvantage of fuyushimoya's approach is that the syntax is more complicated.

Comment: As a matter of fact the result will be the same with closures. I was just wondering why I wasn't able to add a getter to the constructor function. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
function obj(name, lname){
    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = lname;
}
obj.prototype.getfullName = function(){
    return this.name + " " + this.lastName;
}
```

use this as

```
a = new obj("My","Name");
a.getfullName() //"My Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript uses `prototype` inheritance and its functions start with `function` keyword. By convention, object's first character is capitalised.

```
function Obj(name, lname){
    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = lname;
}

Obj.prototype.get = function() {
     return this.name + " " + this.lastName;
}

var person = new Obj('luke', 'lim');
console.log(person.get()); // 'luke lim'
```